# How to set the choice option name in Symfony 4.1?

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony4

After reading many times about [Symfony choices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices), I can't understand how to set the name of the options in my dropdown list?

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('parentCategory', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Category::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'parent category',
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Category::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: if `parentCategory` is a property and you have`getParentCategory()` in your entity - according to manual then `'choice_label' => 'parentCategory',`.

Comment: unfortunately it not helps, still only values in options

Comment: Then iterate over choices and output what you need, in a manual __there's an example__.

Comment: @u_mulder, sorry, but I can't understand how to implement this =(

Comment: There's __an example__, did you read it? Set `choice_attr` as a function with arguments described in __the example__.  Output arguments with `print_r` if you don't know their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by changing `'choice_label' => 'parent category'` to `'choice_label' => 'name'`, and then the output

[image]